# Large Firefox memory consumption on a single webpage

Tags: linux, firefox, memory

How can a single webpage eat 140MB? -

On Firefox 25.0.1 (Linux 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:07:40 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux). I guess I would get the same on a Windows XP session.

```
288.44 MB (100.0%) -- explicit
├──163.55 MB (56.70%) -- window-objects
│  ├──136.91 MB (47.47%) -- top(https://pod51034.outlook.com/owa/#path=/mail, id=78)
```

I do not see much images on that page so I would expect less than 100MB from just looking at the page. If I were to render the image of the page to a RGBA float frame in fullscreen it will take 4*4*1024*768=12 MB so from where does the majority of bytes come? Not from images clearly. There are extensions installed. In total, my session eats 3/5 of my physical 512MB of RAM. (It is an laptop from 2006)

Is it a design strategy: Allocate a lot more than needed just in case, so we do not need to reallocate any buffers?

Comment: you should ask about this microsoft's web developers, not us, not firefox

Comment: You forget about Javascript. You can easily consume 10 GB of memory with a one-liner in JS.

Comment: I agree, HTML5 extensions + Javascript can easily allocate a lot of memory. Today's developpers only optimize their applications in regards to loading time, not memory footprint. Unless you can come up with a huge difference on the same page using another browser, here's your thing.

Comment: @strangewalker probably true, other sites are not that extreme

Comment: @Robert Is that explicit to the developer or not ie var foo=new Array(a_huge_number); If not, Javascript statements are probably way too powerful, but that is a personal opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking at Outlook Web, which uses offline storage if you let it. I'm guessing that is what is causing the large memory footprint.

When I have Outlook Web open in Firefox, `about:memory` says js-compartment is the largest culprit:

```
122.37 MB ++ js-compartment(https://pod000.outlook.com/owa/)
```

Comment: I did not allowed that. Can offline storage be configured to use disk instead?